# Drawing to Multiple Windows Using Vulkan

Tags: c++, window, rendering, vulkan

I am trying to create an application that could dynamically create additional windows. Each window will be drawn to using Vulkan and I know that this means that each window will have to contain it's own SwapChain resources (image views, framebuffers, etc.) and graphics pipeline (as it is references the swap chain's extents). I am wondering if each window will also have to remember its own present queue family or if I can assume that the same queue family can be used for each window. Specifically to find a present queue family you need to find out if a particular queue family supports surface presentation using:

```
VkResult vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(
    VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, 
    uint32_t queueFamilyIndex, 
    VkSurfaceKHR surface, 
    VkBool32* pSupported);
```

This requires a `VkSurfaceKHR` and thus the `HWND` and `HINSTANCE` of a particular window, but I'm not sure if the present queue family is likely to change between different windows created by the same operating system or if I can safely use the same one for each window.

Similarly while reviewing [swap chain recreation within the vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Swap_chain_recreation) I read that `VKSurfaceFormatKHR::format` rarely changes during window resize and that is the only reason the **render pass** needs to be reconstructed during the window resizing operation. How safe would it be to skip the render pass recreation in this step during window resizing and how well could the same render pass be used for different windows?

If each window uses a similar graphics pipeline, more specifically uses the same synchronization objects, would it be typical to have each window append to the same command buffer and use a single `vkQueueSubmit`? I only ask because you need to create a command buffer for each frame in flight, and thus the number of command buffers required would be `numWindows * numFramesInFlight` which feels excessive, but I'm not sure if it would be any different from a single large command buffer (appended to by each window) per frame in flight.

As an aside, the resources for drawing to multiple windows using Vulkan seems to be fairly scarce, so if anyone knows of any good ones I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you could largely assume everything can render to everything. But use you should check that is so anyway. `vkGetPhysicalDeviceWin32PresentationSupportKHR` does not need surface, and gives a strong hint that the device\queue is a presentation able, and not e.g. compute accelerator or something.

> Similarly while reviewing swap chain recreation within the vulkan-tutorial I read that `VKSurfaceFormatKHR::format` rarely changes during window resize and that is the only reason the render pass needs to be reconstructed

It is not supposed to ever change for the lifetime of the physical device and surface. If it could change, that would be a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) problem.

> If each window uses a similar graphics pipeline, more specifically uses the same synchronization objects, would it be typical to have each window append to the same command buffer and use a single `vkQueueSubmit`?

Why not. I mean there is nothing "typical" about this. But if it can be done, then it should probably be done. Otherwise if the windows are unrelated then they should probably have each their own private logical device (or even instance).

> As an aside, the resources for drawing to multiple windows using Vulkan seems to be fairly scarce

Lot of resources for Vulkan are "scarce". That is because Vulkan is like a lego. Once you know what the individual pieces do, then you can build whatever without needing outside help. Drawing to multiple windows is no different than drawing to a single window, exept you do it multiple times.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, if I was not targeting Windows then I might need to create a physical device for each window. I might not understand why but I could at least follow along by assuming that anything that if the creation of a vulkan object requests a specific surface, that the object may vary between surfaces depending on the platform, but then in what situation would I need to make each window have its own private logical device or instance? Would it be only in the cases where some windows use features that others don't require?

Comment: @Ryoku I think on Android, and modern desktop Linux distros with Xinerama it should also not be a problem.

Comment: A thing I would want to know is about rendering different windows (with separate surfaces) on different threads, also how many max out.  And how one would handle the swap chain situation as with the OS "desktop" all windows are composited with each other into a single buffer.